# Rails js.erb file and append

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

How can I append this in js.erb

```
<%= @images.each do |f| %>

    <div class="someclass"><%= image_tag(f.image) %>

<% end %>
```

This doesn't work. I have also tried with escape_javascript...

```
$('.gallery_container').append('

<% @images.each do |f|  %>
    <div class="someclass"><%= link_to image_tag(f.image), "#"  %>    </div>
<% end %>   

')
```

Comment: Does a simple `alert("Hello")` in the .js.erb file work?

Comment: no... but when I put for example only $('.gallery).append('adcd') - alert work

Comment: Is it a `partial` file ?

Comment: no it's a js.erb no partial

Comment: Try this `$("#gallery_container").append("<%= escape_javascript(render  'your_file.html.erb' ) %>");`

Comment: View source, figure  out what's wrong. We can't help you if you're only going to tell us it "doesn't work".

Comment: $('. gallery_container').append('<div class="someclass">' + '<%= link_to image_tag(f.image), "#"  %>' + '</div>')  - THIS works, so thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<% str = "" %>
<% @images.each do |f|  %>
    str += '<div class="someclass">' + '<%= link_to image_tag(f.image), "#"  %>' + '</div>'
<% end %> 

$('.gallery_container').append(str.html_safe)
```

Comment: no this doesn't work to. I see div-s in response with right image but they doesnt show on page

Comment: Is your container `.gallery` or `.gallery_container`

Comment: Yes, it exists... i response for You answer i see sr+ <div> + <a> ... it looks good but sr+ and + are not quoted...

Comment: can you add html_safe and try again.  I have updated my answer

Comment: nothing change - i still see this in preview str += '<div class="someclass">' + '<a href="#"><img alt="03472

Comment: $('. gallery_container').append('<div class="someclass">' + '<%= link_to image_tag(f.image), "#" %>' + '</div>') - THIS works, so thanks :)